# Format latex chapter and ToC

Tags: titlesec, books

I am trying to get my chapter title as
[image]

And the ToC with Title, Date and page number.

As of now, I have only managed the date with `vspace`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage[explicit,compact]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\bfseries\huge}{\filright\huge Experiment \thechapter.}{1ex}{\huge\filright #1}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{My title with date}
\vspace{-1.5in}\hfill Date: 05/10/2023\vspace{1in}
\section*{Aim:}
Hello

\end{document}
```

with table of contents just not managed.

I have also tried:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage[explicit,compact]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\normalfont}{Date: #1 \\\filright\huge Experiment \thechapter.}{1ex}{\huge\filright #2}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{05/10/23}{My title with date}
\section*{Aim:}
Hello

\end{document}
```

which is not working either.

Can you please check how to get the chapter title and ToC properly?